Web-to-Lead : Editing an existing lead instead of creating a new one
I'm new to apex and trying to accomplish the following. We use Salesforce Enterprise edition.
We have a web-to-lead form that passes information about resource downloads and it has basic information fields of the visitor and a custom field that stores a description about the resource the visitor downloaded.
A visitor can download one or more resources and each download get logged in a database table. using a cron the server sends the download details to salesforce to create a lead. thus a new lead is created.
if the visitor downloaded a resource after a lead has been created, a new lead will be created with the download details. We need to avoid this and amend the existing lead details with the new download details. to accomplish this i've come up with the following trigger
trigger UpdateLeadDescription on Lead (before insert) {
    // Map to store existing leads by email
    Map<String, Lead> existingLeads = new Map<String, Lead>();

    // Query existing leads by email
   List<Lead> existingLeadList = [SELECT Id, Description FROM Lead WHERE Email IN (SELECT Email FROM :Trigger.new)];
    
    // Populate the map
    for (Lead existingLead : existingLeadList) {
        existingLeads.put(existingLead.Email, existingLead);
    }

    // Iterate through new leads
    for (Lead newLead : Trigger.new) {
        if (existingLeads.containsKey(newLead.Email)) {
            // Lead exists, append description
            Lead existingLead = existingLeads.get(newLead.Email);
            newLead.Description = existingLead.Description + '\n' + newLead.Description;
        }
    }
}

but the developer console of salesforce throws errors in line number 6.
List<Lead> existingLeadList = [SELECT Id, Description FROM Lead WHERE Email IN (SELECT Email FROM :Trigger.new)];
The error thrown is
Unexpected token '<'.
Please help me to debug this error

The error is due to the incorrect use of the IN clause with a subquery in your SOQL statement. You can't directly use a subquery to filter records in the way you're attempting. Instead, you need to extract the emails from the Trigger.new records and use them in a separate query.
trigger UpdateLeadDescription on Lead (before insert) {
        // Set to store emails from new leads
        Set<String> newLeadEmails = new Set<String>();

        // Populate the set with emails from Trigger.new
        for (Lead newLead : Trigger.new) {
                newLeadEmails.add(newLead.Email);
        }

        // Query existing leads by email
        List<Lead> existingLeadList = [SELECT Id, Email, Description FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :newLeadEmails];

        // Map to store existing leads by email
        Map<String, Lead> existingLeads = new Map<String, Lead>();

        // Populate the map
        for (Lead existingLead : existingLeadList) {
                existingLeads.put(existingLead.Email, existingLead);
        }

        // Iterate through new leads
        for (Lead newLead : Trigger.new) {
                if (existingLeads.containsKey(newLead.Email)) {
                        // Lead exists, append description
                        Lead existingLead = existingLeads.get(newLead.Email);
                        newLead.Description = existingLead.Description + '\n' + newLead.Description;
                }
        }
}

Update 28/10/2024
I have tried below code in my org and working fine.
trigger UpdateLeadDescription on Lead (after insert) {
    // Set to store emails from new leads
    Set<String> setOfNewLeadEmails = new Set<String>();
    
    // Populate the set with emails from Trigger.new
    for (Lead newLead : Trigger.new) {
        setOfNewLeadEmails.add(newLead.Email);
    }
    
    if(setOfNewLeadEmails.size() > 0) {
        // Map to store existing leads by email
        Map<String, List<Lead>> mapOfExistingLeads = new Map<String, List<Lead>>();
        
        // Query existing leads by email
        for (Lead existingLead : [SELECT Id, Email, Description FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :setOfNewLeadEmails AND ID NOT IN :trigger.new]) {
            if(!mapOfExistingLeads.containsKey(existingLead.Email)) {
                mapOfExistingLeads.put(existingLead.Email, new List<Lead>());
            }
            mapOfExistingLeads.get(existingLead.Email).add(existingLead);
        }
        
        //list to store the lead which needs to update
        List<Lead> listOfLeadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();    
        List<Lead> listOfLeadsToDelete = new List<Lead>();
        // Iterate through new leads
        for (Lead newLead : Trigger.new) {            
            if (newLead.Email != null) {                
                if (mapOfExistingLeads.containsKey(newLead.Email)) {
                    // Lead exists, append description
                    for (Lead existingLead : mapOfExistingLeads.get(newLead.Email)) {
                        existingLead.Description = existingLead.Description + ' \n ' + newLead.Description;
                        listOfLeadsToUpdate.add(existingLead);
                    }   
                    listOfLeadsToDelete.add(new Lead(Id = newLead.Id));
                }
            }            
        }
        
        //Update the existing leads
        if (listOfLeadsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
            update listOfLeadsToUpdate;
        }
        
        if (listOfLeadsToDelete.size() > 0) {
            Database.delete(listOfLeadsToDelete);
        }
    }
}

I have tested the code. Before new lead create description look like this: 
After the new lead is created with same email description will be updated on existing lead.

Thank you so much Sir, I was scratching my head as to what was wrong. Now it compiles fine. :-)

Sir, I have tested this in the sandbox descriptions are merged fine but after that, salesforce creates a duplicate lead as well. how to avoid this.  What i want is when there is already  a lead with the same email, append the new description to the existing one and stop creating another lead.

You can update last for loop like this: // Iterate through new leads         for (Lead newLead : Trigger.new) {                 if (existingLeads.containsKey(newLead.Email)) {                         // Lead exists, append description                         Lead existingLead = existingLeads.get(newLead.Email);                         existingLead.Description = existingLead.Description + '\n' + newLead.Description; newLead.addError('A lead with this email already exists. The description has been updated.');                 }         }

Sir I tried with this code but it doesn't append to the Description of the existing lead. I received the error email.

@Desper, I have updated the code and added in answer.

Hi sir, let me test this, Thank you so much :)

nope sir, it does delete the new lead but doesn't append the new description to the old one.

@Desper, I have tested the same code in my org and working as expected. See the screenshots, I have added in the answer.

@thushar-jadav Sir, I'm getting an error "System.ListException: Invalid id at index 0: null: Trigger.trigger_merge_description: line 88, column 1" it means this line "  if (listOfLeadsToDelete.size() > 0) {"

@Desper, Make sure that your trigger is After Trigger not the Before Trigger.

That was the case Sir, Thank you, how can i deploy this to the live org? because I'm getting an error saying "Cannot create apex trigger on an active org"

@Desper, You need to create this trigger in the sandbox first, test it in the sandbox and then deploy it to production.

Hi Sir, Yes I'm testing this on the sandbox. how can i deploy it to the live org?

You need to create a changeset and add your trigger and test class for this trigger in the changeset and then you can deploy this changeset to production. After successfully deploying the changeset from the sandbox to production, you need to log in to the production and validate and deploy the changeset on production. - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382677&type=1

Thank you sir, I'll follow this article. Many thanks again. You have a good day now :-)

Good day sir, When i tried to deploy i'm getting this strange error. Pleas help me to debug this. https://i.ibb.co/BfVwxFD/image-7.png When I ran this on Developer org it had 81% code coverage.
